# How to disable any incoming phone calls while running web app in smartphones?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to disable any incoming phone calls while running a web app in mobile devices such as tablet or smartphone(iOS, Android)?

I have tried 
`<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">` in the html5 but it does not work at all. And I don't know how to do this in JavaScript

The reason is our projects is to run a web app on the mobile devices to play multiple audio clips to children. We don't want incoming phone calls to interrupt the audio clips.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I certainly hope there is no possible way to do this. What a nightmare for the user and what a security problem for the phone.

Comment: I agree. I would be astounded if this was possible on any phone.

Comment: `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">` is meant to prevent phone numbers from appearing as links on a page, not to prevent phone calls.

Comment: Sorry. I should be more clear. The reason is that my team's project is running a web app on smart phones to play audio clips to children. We don't want the audio clips to get interrupted while playing. It's totally about 10 minutes. Is it still possible?

Comment: You should not be able to turn off the "phone" part of a phone, even for 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

This is completely impossible on any non modified mobile phone, the operating systems for ios, android, blackberry, and windows phone all have zero apis for interacting with low level phone settings.

You may be able to read if the phone is in airplane mode and not allow the application to continue until it is. If it's important to the operation. But it is up to the user not the application to decide if you should allow phone calls.

Answer (score 0):

Before the parent hands over the phone to the child, remind the parent to put his phone on airplane mode so the child can work with the app in full concentration uninterrupted.

This way you give the choice to to the parent instead of forcing unexpected behaviour.